# Access HttpContext.Current.Application from separate console app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, console-application, httpcontext

I'd like to be able to clear particular cache items from a console application running on the same server as the ASP.NET website.

If I reference System.Web and then try System.Web.HttpContext.Current I always get null, which sort of makes sense.

I tried by this code and System.Web.HttpContext.Current became not null.

Code:

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
    new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", ""),
    new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())
    );

// User is logged in
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(
    new GenericIdentity("username"),
    new string[0]
    );

// User is logged out
HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(
    new GenericIdentity(String.Empty),
    new string[0]
    );
```

But HttpContext.Current.Application cannot use. I try by this:

```
..
HttpContext.Current.Application.Add("TestValue", 1);
..
object objReturn = HttpContext.Current.Application.Get("TestValue");
if(objReturn==null)
    Console.WriteLine("objReturn is null");
else
   Console.WriteLine(objReturn);
```

My problem is that the variable `objReturn` is always null.
Anyone else have better ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: How about a different approach, such as exposing a Web service that the console app can call to remove the cache items?

Comment: @Tuan Can you give me a sample solution about exposing Web service that the console app can call to remove the cache items,pls?

Answer (score 3):

The cache lives inside the ASP.NET worker process, you cannot access it directly from a console application. HttpContext.Current is null since you're not in a web context.

I would add a web page to the application itself that allows you to clear the cache items.

Comment: thanks for advice,I am trying this.Can you give me a sample solution pls?

Comment: A simple page with a button would do, try to do it yourself, and ask here if you're having trouble